# How to show custom 404 pages for URLs which has a file path of a php file

Tags: php, html, url, http-status-code-404, lampp

I have a custom 404.php file in the root folder.
My .htaccess looks like:

```
Options +MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

When I visit URLs like `localhost/blah`, this 404 page loads correctly.
But for urls like:
`localhost/departments/civil/blah` it does not show the 404 page because I have a file with path `/departments/civil.php`. So Xampp is loading this civil.php file rather than the 404 file (which it should because of the /blah).

(Also, the civil.php file which is loaded has broken CSS links now as the href for CSS files in civil.php is `../css/civil.css`, but since we have /blah in the url the path becomes `localhost/departments/css/civil.css`, rather than `localhost/css/civil.css`.)

How do I show the 404 page correctly for such URLs?

My folder structure:

```
|__/departments
|  |__civil.php
|
|__/css
|__|__civil.css
|
|__.htaccess
|
|__404.php
```

Also, don't know if this matters or not, but, I have set my DocumentRoot in xampp config file to my project name so that I don't have to go to localhost/<project-name> but only to localhost/ to view the project directly.

EDIT:
I can use the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to see if there's anything after `localhost/departments/civil`, but I'll have to do this for all the php files I have. Is there any better option?

Comment: @Austin I am using PHP 8.0.7. 
The code you sent is for setting the error code and showing the 404 page, but where do I add this code? 
The URL where the 404 is not loading is: `localhost/departments/civil/blah` because I have a file at the path `localhost/departments/civil.php`, and that file is loaded rather than the 404 page.
So, the response code is 200 every time. I want to show the 404 page when I go to `localhost/departments/civil/blah`

Comment: @Austin I have already made a .htaccess and provided it's contents in the question